# Reference list object by a variable is different than for (some) other objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

In defining variable of a list object, for example:

```
x = [1,2,0.2,3,4]
y = x
x.sort()
```

I would expect that `y` is still equal to `[1, 2, 0.2, 3, 4]`, but it does not. The value of `y` changed as `x` changed. To counter this, I found that using `y = x.copy()` can preserve the value in the first line.

On the other hand, another example :

```
x = 5
y = x
x = 4
```

from this the value of `y` is still `5`, it does not change as `x` change.

My question : is this due to the design in list's class, or there is another explanation? I found the dynamic change also happen when using `x.append(value)`. Any insight is appreciated. Regards, Arief

Comment: Obligatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @Arief I just saw that you re-included the "Any insight is appreciated. Regards, Arief". Such salutations are [considered "noise" that distracts from the question itself (and should be avoided or removed)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every variable is just a pointer to an Python object, if you have two variables pointing to the same object then you'll see the changes in each of them (and `.sort` works in-place, if you want a new `list` you should use `x = sorted(x)`). However if you re-assign a variable then it will point to a different object.

---

I included some images to better visualize what's happening (not high-quality but I hope it conveys the message).

```
x = [1,2,0.2,3,4]
y = x
```

[image]

If you `copy` (it's a shallow copy so the list-contents still refer to the same items!):

```
x = [1,2,0.2,3,4]
y = x.copy()
```

[image]

Your second case is just the same:

```
x = 5
y = x
```

[image]

But then you re-assign the variable `x` (so it points to another object thereafter):

```
x = 4
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the insight and answer. So it is not like if `x = [1, 2, 3]`, then `x` has value `[1, 2, 3]`. But, from what I understand, it simply means the list object `[1, 2, 3]` can being called by `x`. If a variable refer to another variable : `y = x`, then it can be perceived as passing reference two times, calling `y` is as same as calling `x` and then calling the existing object `[1, 2, 3]`. They depend on the same object. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, `y` and `x` are just references to the class list.

When you do something like:

```
y=x
```

You are coping the reference of the class and not creating another one.

When using `copy` you are doing a *shallow copy* that are creating a new class, copying all elements again to this new object.

[Python manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) presents a explanation and others operators used to actually copy a full class.