# why did the value of "x" change?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
x = [[1],[1],[1],[-1]]
a = [[-2,-1,-1,-2],[1,-2,2,-1],[-1,-2,-2,-1],[2,-1,1,-2]]
h = 0.1
def K(h,a,x):
    cont = [1,2,3,4]
    k = []
    for i in range(len(cont)):
        k.append(h*cont[i])
    y = x
    print('original value',x)
    for j in range(len(y)):
        y[j][0] += k[j]/4
        print('modified value',x)
K(h,a,x)
```

So the question is why did the value of `x` change if it has not received anything?

Comment: Because you changed `y` and `y` is just `x`. To copy a value you need to actually copy it `y = copy.deepcopy(x)`.

Comment: but it does not make sense to me,for exemple, if i put x = 3, y = x and y+= 5, the valeu of x will not change

Comment: this strange behavior applies to lists, not to integers. That's why x = 3... behaves as you expect.

Comment: `y += 5` is like `y = y + 5`. `y + 5` creates a new value, which you then assign to `y`. In this case, no new value is being created; you’re just modifying the same list.

Comment: @DanielFang I answered a similar question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44401491/5393381 You might want to take a look. Also `y+=5` doesn't work in-place for integers. For integers it's just a short form of `y = y + 5`.

Comment: @JulianCienfuegos: That’s extremely misleading. Integers are immutable, and `y = y + [5]` wouldn’t change a list `y`.

Comment: @DanielFang In general you could avoid doing all the in-place changes and just use comprehensions to create the new values and return them: https://gist.github.com/MSeifert04/cf526882ddb94bf0cb9f428a9a738814

Comment: so, it occurs just with list, and there is no problem if i do the same with integers,right?

Comment: No, it will happen with almost everything that is not explicitly immutable. It's more that numbers (but also strings) are the exception.

Comment: @MSeifert  
i changed y = x to y = x[:] but it does not work

Comment: I Know that it doesn't work. I already gave you two working solutions. Just use one of These.

Comment: check my edit, I found the problem

Comment: @MSeifert i also tried y = copy.deepcopy(x), but it says 'NameError: name 'copy' is not defined'

Comment: @rosh i put y = deepcopy(x) but it results in NameError: name 'deepcopy' is not defined

Comment: you need to import it, 'from copy import deepcopy' - put that at the top and it will work.

Comment: @rosh thanks! i got it

Comment: No problem, super easy to miss. Would appreciate it if you could accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put:

```
y = x
```

All x is doing is acting as a pointer to the list object in memory. When you do the above, you are saying I want y to point to the same list that x references in the memory. Any changes in place changes to y will also affect x.

If you wish to have the reference y point to a different object in memory (with the same values as x,) you need to make a copy of x.

```
y = x[:] #make a copy.  SEE EDIT
```

Now y and x will be pointing to different list objects in memory, but both objects will have the same values.

Note that any mutable datatype in python shares this reference property, such as: sets, dictionaries, lists, byte arrays and also some classes.

Look into the differences between mutable and immutable datatypes in python as this distinction is critical and will lead to undiagnosible bugs without knowledge on how python accesses different data types.

**EDIT!!**

Sorry, I did not notice x is made of a series of lists. You need to use deepcopy to copy the nested lists!

```
from copy import deepcopy
y = deepcopy(x)
```

Comment: i changed y = x to y = x[:] but it does not work

Comment: Check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
y = x
```

You're literally saying that `x` equals `y`. This doesn't make a copy of `x`. Whatever you do to `x` will happen to `y` and vice versa. You need to make a copy of `x` if you want them to be independent.

Comment: how can i copy it? i tried y = x[:] and y = list(x), but both of them failed, the valeu of x is still changing